# Replace values by indices of corresponding to another array

Tags: numpy

I am a newbie in numpy. I have an array A of size [x,] of values and an array B of size [y,] (y > x). I want as result an array C of size [x,] filled with indices of B.

Here is an example of inputs and outputs:

```
>>> A = [10, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 10, 50, 20]
>>> B = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> C = #Some operations
>>> C
[0,  1,  2,  0,  3,  4,  0,  4, 1]
```

I didn't find the way how to do this. Please advice me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), assuming that `B` is sorted increasingly:

```
C = np.searchsorted(B,A)
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 4, 1])
```

---

**Update** for general situation where `B` is not sorted. We can do an `argsort`:

```
# let's swap 40 and 50 in B
# expect the output to have 3 and 4 swapped
B = [10, 20, 30, 50, 40]

BB = np.sort(B)

C = np.argsort(B)[np.searchsorted(BB,A)]
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 3, 0, 3, 1], dtype=int64)
```

You can double check:

```
(np.array(B)[C] == A).all()
# True
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in my real array B is not sorted, so it is not working in case of
A = np.array([10, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 10, 50, 20])
B = np.array([40, 50, 10, 20, 30])
C = np.searchsorted(B,A)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to sort B, because order of B array is important for next steps of my code :(

Answer (score 1):

For general python lists

```
A = [10, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 10, 50, 20]
B = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]


C = [A.index(e) for e in A if e in B]

print(C)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
A = np.array([10, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 10, 50, 20])
B = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

np.argmax(B==A[:,None],axis=1)
```